# mouseMove very laggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to obtain the image effect that 99designs is obtaining when hovering a mouse over a design.. [[99designs.ca] Logo design contest: Runningbug Needs Logo 220626](http://99designs.ca/logo-design/contests/runningbug-needs-logo-220626)

I am currently obtaining the position of the mouse on mousemove, then using that to move my popover `<img>`, and everything works fine, but it is *very* laggy.. and presumably its from so many calls being made.

To get the position of the mouse:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   //$("#special").click(function(e){
   $(".imgWrap").mousemove(function(e){
      //$('#status2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
      //alert(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
      mouseX = e.pageX;
      mouseY = e.pageY;
   }); 
})
```

I'm not sure of another way I can do this.. any ideas?

On the full course of events is the following:

1. User mouses over an img tag.
2. I get the position of the mouse as per above.
3. The `<img>` tag also calls a js function which changes the position of an img tag to the position of the mouse.

Actually, you can check it here: [pokemonsite](http://pokemonpacific.com/index2)

update: I see there is a bounty placed (thanks !). I'm a little busy at the moment and can't check all the other answers, but I'll make sure to check them asap

Comment: You could try handling the vanilla JavaScript `mousemove` event. What exactly is your code doing every mousemove? It shouldn't be that laggy, because you shouldn't have to do "many calls being made". As you say, you're just grabbing the position of the mouse, and moving another element. That shouldn't make anything laggy

Comment: Please add the img move code to your question. (Don't just link to an external site, and if you _do_ link to an external site please use a clickable link.)

Comment: sorry this is the updated link: http://pokemonpacific.com/index2

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but if you used code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nmPcw/ , it doesn't seem to lag. I tried looking through your code on the site, but it's spread out and is confusing

Comment: If it's jQuery use the jQuery tag, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to improve performance when using mousemove events.

1. Use `backface-visibility: hidden` on popover element to force hardware acceleration. Same thing can be achived with `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` but that makes difficult to use CSS `transform` function (see point #2).
2. Use CSS `transform` function for absolute positioning to avoid repaints but keep popover element absolute or fixed positioned.
3. When setting inline CSS via JS use requestAnimationFrame to avoid unnecesary layout trashing.
4. (maybe, optionally) hide cursor when hovering and use popover element as position indicator.
5. Move everything you can from JS to CSS ie. `:hover` state can be used to toggle display of popover element.

I made demo example combining all things listed. There is still some latency between cursor position and popover image and none of example links in original question work so I can't compare against it but I hope someone finds this useful.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/WbPger)**

```
<div id="imgHolder" class="imgHolder">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="bigImgHolder" class="imgHover">
   <img src="//placehold.it/500x500" alt="" />
</div>
```

```
.imgHover { 
    display: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.imgHolder:hover ~ .imgHover { display: block; }

// uncomment if it makes sense
//.imgHolder:hover { cursor: none; }
```

```
var posX, posY;

$('#imgHolder').mousemove(HoverImg);

function HoverImg(e) {
    posX = e.pageX;
    posY = e.pageY;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(showBigImg);  
}

function showBigImg() {
    $('#bigImgHolder').css({'-webkit-transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px)', 'transform': 'translateX(' + posX + 'px) translateY(' + posY + 'px)' });
}
```

references:

- http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d
- http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/
- https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $(".imgWrap").mousemove(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();

     mouseX = e.pageX;
     mouseY = e.pageY;
    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If the absolute (x, y) position is not so important (meaning: some pixel-values can be omitted without destroying your logic), you could try to skip some frames of your mousemove-event.

```
var globalSkipCounter = 0;
var globalSkipRate = 5;
$(".imgWrap").mousemove(function(e){
   if(globalSkipCounter >= globalSkipRate){
     var mouseX = e.pageX;
     var mouseY = e.pageY;
     do_stuff(mouseX, mouseY);
     globalSkipCounter = 0;
   }
   else{
     globalSkipCounter+=1;
   }
});
```

This way, you omit redrawing your image on every mousemove-event, instead your draw-routines (`do_stuff`) are only invoked, once every 5 events.

Comment: I used this method earlier n tried again on ur solution, but no luck. Moving any image on mouse move gives performance issue. Image lags behind. I am asking this for my Google chrome extension, where i move an image on different website. It works fine on most websites like wikopedia, google.com , but lags on some like gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` or (recommended) `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` instead of pageX and pageY. Maybe this will be a better solution. Note: `offsetx` and `offsety` do not work in Firefox as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Cache the position and wrap the update in an `if(oldpos !== newpos)` type check (remembering to update oldpos inside it).

Use `requestAnimationFrame` to handle the update - if you have a normal function and pass that as the callback then it will only get called once per frame (ie, don't use an anonymous function).

Finally make use of `transform:translate(x,y)` to set the position and make better use of the GPU etc. Related to this, there's no harm in making use of the css [`will-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) keyword if you want to use top/left instead.

Answer (score 1):

try a maximum event per second based approach:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var now, then, delta, interval = 1000/60; //maximum 60 eps, you can change
   //$("#special").click(function(e){
   $(".imgWrap").mousemove(function(e){
     now = Date.now();
     delta = now - then;
     if (delta > interval) {
       then = now - delta % interval; //subtract extra waited time
       //$('#status2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
       //alert(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
       mouseX = e.pageX;
       mouseY = e.pageY;
       // do your thing
     }
   }); 
})
```

EDIT: didn't know then is a reserved word in javascript, you can rename it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sortable listview in angular, but dragging items with the mouse in chrome was lagging a lot. I tried disabling all chrome extensions and now the lag is totally gone.

It turned out that TamperMonkey was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "left" or "right" property of CSS rather try to use
"transform" I was trying to do the same thing as asked in question, and using "transform" worked for me like a charm.

for example:

```
transform: translate(30px);
```

this will move the element, 30px to the right.

by using `transform` we can move elements to left, right, top and bottom according to the need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).